# Logging into WEBMIN make server non responsive

Tags: centos7, webmin

**Update 2**
I have reinstalled the OS, and things are working smoothly now. I suppose there was something wrong with the OS. Thankyou everyone for the quick response.

**Update 1**
To help resolve this, I tried to uninstall and reinstall virtualmin.
and now Im having an error while installation.>

> **Error:** Failed to query Postfix config command to get the current value of parameter virtual_alias_maps: Error
>   ----- Failed to query Postfix config command to get the current value of parameter virtual_alias_maps:
>   -----                                                                     Cleaning up
>
> [WARNING] The following errors occurred during installation:
>
> **◉ Postinstall configuration returned an error.**

First of all I'm new to hosting and everything, to save the cost of WHM I installed WEBMIN using [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-manage-centos-7-server-with-webmin/) on Centos7. Everything went smoothly and I got the message

> You can now access Webmin on https://Your_Server_IP:10000

I used this link and WEBMIN login console appeared, then I provide root user details which I was using for putty while installation. Then I got this message

> This site can’t be reached  took too long to respond.

This was not it, the whole server went down, I is now not accessible from putty, not responding the pings. This is happened second time. After the first time I waited overnight and the server was working the next day. But now it had happened again.

What am I missing here?? Please Help.

Comment: So, if you have a putty connection, and you send your browser to Webmin, the putty connection is cut?

Comment: Yep putty also goes down. The whole server seems to be down for some time. Dont know why.

Comment: Do you have access to a console?  When you installed Webmin, did you install any of the modules?

Comment: Ubuntu instructions say NOT to use root login, but normal login for webmin.